# Unlocking mobile using java android accelerometer.

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, shake

Here is my MainActivity.java file. I want a small application which can just unlock my phone if i shake the phone in specific direction(eg- left right).

what should i do here to make it work?

I saw some related posts on stack overflow as well but so far not got anything related or which i can implement here.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        // The following are used for the shake detection
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private ShakeDetector mShakeDetector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //code from shake
        // ShakeDetector initialization
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector();
        mShakeDetector.setOnShakeListener(new OnShakeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShake(int count) {
                handleShakeEvent(count);
            }
        });
        //code ends
    }
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            // Add the following line to register the Session Manager Listener onResume
            mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeDetector, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            // Add the following line to unregister the Sensor Manager onPause
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mShakeDetector);
            super.onPause();
        }
    protected void handleShakeEvent(int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can check for specific direction your phone is headed using the Accelerometer, maybe try and get that info from another sensor like Gyro or something like that. Anyway, if you could able to get that info using the Accelerometer and if you want to use it whe screen is off you must acquire a Wake Lock which needs manifest permissions.

Comment: Hi, I tried that too..but it didn't help. I am using Nexus 5 and Accelerometer works fine in this model even if the screen is off. That is why I don't understand the problem.